# Spring Authorization Server with the oidcClientRegistrationEndpoint

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

Is it possible in Spring Authorization Server version 1.0.1 to use the oidcClientRegistrationEndpoint?

Is there anyone who knows where a good example can be found.

Thanks

Willy De Keyser

I tried the following code but get an error message not found, I think the endpoint does not exist.

```
@Bean
    AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://localhost:9000")
                .authorizationEndpoint("/oauth2/authorize")
                .tokenEndpoint("/oauth2/token")
                .tokenIntrospectionEndpoint("/oauth2/introspect")
                .tokenRevocationEndpoint("/oauth2/revoke")
                .jwkSetEndpoint("/oauth2/jwks")
                .oidcUserInfoEndpoint("/userinfo")
                .oidcClientRegistrationEndpoint("/connect/register")
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-authorization-server/

Answer (score 0):

It is not enabled by default. You can enable the endpoint via:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
        .oidc(oidc -> oidc
            .clientRegistrationEndpoint(Customizer.withDefaults())
        );

    return http.build();
}
```

See [OpenID Connect 1.0 Client Registration Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#oidc-client-registration-endpoint) in the reference for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try it this way.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error message: "error": "invalid_token" and Client registration request failed: [invalid_token]

Comment: The userinfo, introspect and revoke endpoints work fine with the access token.

Comment: I did it, thanks for the tip. The error was in the Scopes.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Did my answer move you along? If so, please accept it or let me know what could be improved. Thanks!